# Lightbox2 with mobile browser - the last image is light-boxed out of view when scrolling to the bottom of the page 'too quickly'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox2

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lightbox Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/css/lightbox.css">
</head>

  <div>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=1" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test1">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=1" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=2" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test2">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=2" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=3" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test3">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=3" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=4" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test4">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=4" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=5" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test5">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=5" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=6" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test6">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=6" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=7" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test7">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=7" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=8" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test8">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=8" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=9" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test9">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=9" />
    </a>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
```

So I have five images as per the html sample below. Lightbox2 works fine on desktop. On iPhone 13 Max Pro, using both Safari and Chrome, I see the following behaviour:

If I scroll 'quickly' down to the last image (such that the page 'bounces' when it hits the bottom) then subsequently clicking on that last image will produce the required lightbox, but the whole page will reload to the top of the page and the light-boxed image (the last one on the page) cannot be seen. It is down at the bottom, to which you then have to scroll to find it. And there it is, presenting itself as expected.  Clicking on all other images produces lightboxes perfectly positioned, in focus, as expected.

If I scroll 'slowly' to the bottom of the page, and not 'bounce' the bottom of the page, then all works perfectly as expected for the last image when it is pressed.

Has anyone seen this behaviour? Can anyone reproduce it? Thank you.

```
`<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  
  <style>
    .gallery img {
      max-width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0;
    }
  </style>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lightbox Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="images/test/pic1.jpg" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test1">
    <img src="images/test/pic1.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="images/test/pic2.jpg" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test2">
    <img src="images/test/pic2.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="images/test/pic3.jpg" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test3">
    <img src="images/test/pic3.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="images/test/pic4.jpg" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test4">
    <img src="images/test/pic4.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="images/test/pic5.jpg" data-lightbox="test" data-title="test5">
    <img src="images/test/pic5.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

<script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
`
```

Comment: I think in order to help it would be very useful to be able to see the problem for myself. Could you turn your code into a runnable snippet within your question, using images we can see. This link might help you do that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, thank you for that - I am just looking at the best way to self-contain it. Am new here - when I do that, is it best to just 'Edit' my original question? Thank you again.

Comment: Snippet now added. The code works fine on desktop, but I still see the problem on iPhone 13 Pro Max when scrolling fully down to the end of the page. I don't have any other devices to test it on, unfortunately.

Comment: I’ve tried the snippet on an iPad and on iPhone SE and don’t see the problem I’m afraid.

Comment: Thank you for trying it. I have further observed the following: running the snippet in full-screen on my iPhone 13 Pro Max does not reproduce the problem. The problem is not present then. When I host the exact same code (at hostinger.com) I still see the problem on my iPhone with Safari and Chrome. However - when I try the same with both Edge and the Google app (not Chrome, but the Google app), then the problem is not there. Either something odd about the hosting, or it's a renderer / engine oddity.

Comment: Maybe choose some alternative script, like Fancybox.